# recursively call a method but log only second time?

Tags: java, recursion, urldecode

I have a below method which does URL decoding on the value passed along with using charset.

```
  public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      try {
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        // log error
        return null;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Now if `URLDecoder.decode` line throws `UnsupportedEncodingException` first time then I want to run same `value` against below three lines:

```
value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
value = value.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
```

And if then again `URLDecoder.decode` line throws exception second time, then I will log the error but only second time and return null value otherwise return the value which is decoded.

What is the best and elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for any way to do this, or the most elegant solution?

Comment: Adding another try/catch block that I was already aware of it. I was looking for some better or elegant way  to do that if there is any.

Comment: I suggested an edit that appears declined. Where is the recursion here?

Comment: It's not a static method. My decode method and URLDecoder decode method, they are two different methods. I renamed my method to clear this confusion. If you look at the answer of Siddharth, I already did like that but what will be the most elegant way to rewrite that whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a private version of your function signature which includes an extra flag.

```
  private String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset, boolean isFirstTime) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      try {
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
            value = value.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
            return decodeValue(value, charset.name(), false);
        } else {
            // log error
            return null;
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Then, just pass `true` the first time and `false` in the recursive call. Inside the function, only execute the next three lines if `true` is passed.

The public version can pass `true`.

```
  public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
       decodeValue(value, charset, true);
  }
```

Comment: I would make this signature private.

Comment: @merlin2011 How will I use this boolean variable to execute three  lines and do the logging as well. Got slightly confused, can you provide an example how would that work.

Comment: just to let you know my decode method and `URLDecoder.decode` method they are two different methods. I updated my question to change the method name. In your case, you are passing false to URLDecoder method which doesn't take that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't recursive, you could make use of a while loop and a flag.

```
public String decode(String value, Charset charset) {
    boolean first = true;
    while(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        try {
            return value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            if(first == false) {
                // Log error.
                return null;
            }
            value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25").replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
        }
        first = false;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
 public String decode(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      try {
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        try {
        value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
        value = value.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        // log error
        return null;
      }
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: And it does duplicate code. That is most often not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a flag is **one** option. Yes, it is the easier one; but many people argue that having *flags* is simply spoken: bad practice.

You simply try to minimize those things.

In other words: if you have a method that should behave **differently** for the first and subsequent calls; consider creating **two** methods there. Of course, you avoid code duplication as far as possible, but unless it becomes to costly, you should at least consider avoiding such flag arguments, too.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how can I use two different methods here and what  to call depending on when the exception is thrown and calling it normally?

Answer (score 0):

Here is version without extra flags, duplicated code, recursion and loops:

```
public String decodeValue(final String value, Charset charset) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String result;
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        UnsupportedEncodingException[] lastException = new UnsupportedEncodingException[1];
        result = Stream.<Function<String, String>>of(
                Function.identity(),
                s -> {
                    s = s.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
                    s = s.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
                    return s;
                })
                .map(f -> f.apply(value))
                .map(appliedValue -> {
                    try {
                        return URLDecoder.decode(appliedValue, charset.name());
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        lastException[0] = e;
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> lastException[0]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here I just take stream with 2 functions: identity and function making string correction. Then I apply these functions to initial string and try to decode. If first attempt is successful then code will not apply correction function and just return correct result. If decoder throws exception after value correction then "findFirst" will not find any value. Then we throw last caught exception.

Comment: Can you  provide an example with Java7. I cannot use Java 8 as of now. If I can avoid extra flags, duplicated code in Java 7, then it will be good. So far I haven't got an answer like that.

Comment: In this case Mattew's solution is preferable.